# React-redux and React Navigation connect method gives a TypeError

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm getting a `TypeError` from **React-redux** `connect` function when exporting my component to **React Navigation**.

**My Component**

```
import { logout, login } from './common/redux/actions/index.js'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class AuthenticateUser extends React.Component{
 ....

   render(){ 
    return (
     <View>
      <Text>Login stuff goes here...</Text> 
     </View>
    );
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      user: state.user
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      logout: logout,
      login: login,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(AuthenticateUser);
```

**React-Navigation Component**

```
  import AuthenticateUser from './AuthenticateUser';

  export const MainTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
   {
    ...
    AuthenticateUser:{ 
      screen: AuthenticateUser, 
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'Me',
      }
    },
   });
  const AppNav = createAppContainer(MainTabNav);
  export default AppNav;
```

When i `export` my component without `connect` it works. Any suggestion on how i can get around this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So after some good sleep and more coffee, i found that i needed to **export** my **Component** with `createAppContainer`. It works now.

```
export const authComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(AuthenticateUser);
export default createAppContainer(authComponent);
```